# Providing a join count and total count in the same query with Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

One **style** has many **reviews**.

Let's say I am doing:

```
Style.select('styles.id').
    joins(:reviews).
    select('reviews.style_id, count(reviews.id) AS review_count')
```

... but I also want to know the total number of reviews! Is it possible to pull that information as well. I tried count(*) as total_reviews, but this still returns the review count per style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think in SQL, you are building up a lot of rows (well, a subset of that lot), and in each row you are putting a count for that row.

On the other side, you want a total count. Which of the retrieved records should have that total and in which column/attribute?

It's not that you can't do that in rails, it's that you can't do that in SQL itself.
The resultsets are completely different, so you need two queries, so you need two ActiveRecord calls.

A different way to approach this (again you need two separaate queries, but they are simpler) is to use a counter_cache for `@style.reviews`:

```
# add a 'reviews_count' integer column to the 'styles' table and use it as 
# a counter cache as follows
class Review < AR::Base
  belongs_to :style, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Now you have the counts without the need of a join, and the total count can be obtained with a simple sum.

**Addendum:** To use the ocounter cache, query the `styles` table as always (without includes or joins), and call

```
@style.reviews.size
```

whenever you want to get the count of the reviews. This won't make another query, instead will use the cached counter on the `@style` instance itself.

Comment: You lost me with that final paragraph. What total count?

Comment: You say "... but I also want to know the total number of reviews!". Now that you have a column with the specific reviews count, to obtain the total of reviews for a selection of styles you just sum the corresponding counters.

Comment: Thanks. What a bummer though! I need to access both in a single query in order to calculate a beyesian average for a jquery data table performing an ajax call.

Comment: You can perform two queries in a single ajax call... Try to state the requirements for your returned data, so you can set up your controller the right way. Two queries in a single web request are not a big deal.

Comment: Sorry for being vague.. actually it's a bit trickier than that. I'm Using Ryan Bates' custom class to re-order the columns, and unfortunately my 'rank' column has to be calculated on the fly, using a single query.  https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-340/store-after/app/datatables/products_datatable.rb

Comment: Oh then you want to use database's rank functions, not simple sums. This is database-specific, and some of them do not implement them at all.